# Microsoft.Kinect not found in kinect 2.0

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working with Kinect 2.0 sdk. I am trying to add Microsoft.Kinect as a reference to my visual studio project 2012 but there is no such extension in the sdk folder. Where can I find the sdk? Has it been removed or is it a problem with my installation?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkxVk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Kinect nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Kinect/). Kinect 2.0 SDK doesn't contain the reference files.